# ixudra get to localhost

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I try to send curl to localhost with package called [ixudra](https://github.com/ixudra/curl) in laravel.
here is the code :

```
$url = 'localhost/fa_quality/public/api/qualities';
$response = Curl::to($url)
->enableDebug('./logFile.txt')
->get();        
return  $response;
```

but it's always return like below :
[image]

I tried my end point API postman, it work fine.

I try another end point such as `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` with `withProxy` method in ixudra and it work fine.

Im using xampp version 3.2.2. my computer run under proxy.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: try adding `http` in localhost URL

Comment: already did that. no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt this has anything to do with the package. Most likely it's your setup. Usually when I see this, it's because your local webserver doesn't know how to interpret the "localhost" URL that you're using. Your Postman is an app that "lives" inside your host OS (I'm assuming Windows), which knows that an http request for "localhost" needs to be redirected to the VM instead of the internet.

I don't know xampp very well, but I work on Mac with an Ubuntu VM using vagrant. I'd fix this by SSH-ing into my VM and editing the hosts file to redirect HTTP calls FROM the VM to url "localhost" back TO the VM itself by adding the line `127.0.0.1     localhost`. I would assume you can do something similar on xampp, but no idea how it works, sorry.